# Проблема со сборкой tesseract-3.04.01

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Здраствуйте, у меня возникает ошибка при сборке tesserect-3.04.01. Делал по [этой статьи](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#Compilation). При вводе команды `make` возникают ошибки:

```
...
mv -f .deps/tesseract-tesseractmain.Tpo .deps/tesseract-tesseractmain.Po
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -std=c++11   -o     tesseract tesseract-tesseractmain.o libtesseract.la   -lrt -llept -lpthread 
libtool: link: g++ -std=c++11 -o .libs/tesseract tesseract-    tesseractmain.o  ./.libs/libtesseract.so -lrt -llept -lpthread
./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `l_generateCIDataForPdf'
./.libs/libtesseract.so: undefined reference to `l_CIDataDestroy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tesseract] Ошибка 1    make[2]: Выход из каталога `/home    /max/tesseract-3.04.01dev/api'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Ошибка 1
make[1]: Выход из каталога `/home/max/tesseract-3.04.01dev'
make: *** [all] Ошибка 2
```

Собирал на версии 3.02 та же ошибка.
Собираю все на Ubuntu 14.04. Где может быть ошибка?

Comment: Судя по этому обсуждению https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/ulDLjqhr8wQ вам необходимо использовать Leptonica 1.71

Comment: у меня стоит leptonica 1.73, но либа все ровно не собирается